# How to trigger back button from Ionic5 code

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic5

I need to trigger the same function and the back button in the nav menu would trigger from code.

```
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
```

I am currently using

```
    this.router.navigate(['/previousPage', {
        demoMode: false
    }]);
```

but there is a weird inconsistency with D3 on the start view that does not occur with the back button yet happens with the `router`. I just do not know which function the back button triggers in the background. Guess it must be something similar to `navCtrl.pop` ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-how-to-programmaticaly-navigate-back-with-angular-router/156482/2

Comment: I think I did in a way, I had `navCtrl` and that caused other issues so that I resorted to having `router` only. I might try again though since the issue I have now is more severe than the other.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know these things is by taking a look at Ionic's source code. Ionic's source code is super well organised so most of the times it's super easy to find what some components do behind the scenes.

Regarding your question, **[this is the code of the ion-back-button directive](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/angular/src/directives/navigation/ion-back-button.ts)**.

Based on that, seems like Ionic uses the `IonRouterOutlet` if it's available or the `NavController` otherwise:

```
if (this.routerOutlet && this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) {
  this.navCtrl.setDirection('back', undefined, undefined, this.routerAnimation);
  this.routerOutlet.pop();
  // ...
} else if (defaultHref != null) {
  this.navCtrl.navigateBack(defaultHref, { animation: this.routerAnimation });      
}
```

So knowing that, you can write a method that does exactly the same thing. Please take a look at **[this Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66496101?file=src/app/pages/details/details.page.ts)**.

The most relevant part of the code is the `DetailsPage`:

```
import { Component, Optional } from "@angular/core";
import { IonRouterOutlet, NavController } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-details",
  templateUrl: "./details.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./details.page.scss"]
})
export class DetailsPage {
  constructor(
    @Optional() private routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet,
    private navCtrl: NavController
  ) {}

  public goBack(): void {
    if (this.routerOutlet && this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) {
      this.navCtrl.setDirection("back");
      this.routerOutlet.pop();
    } else {
      this.navCtrl.navigateBack("/home");
    }
  }
}
```

In the demo I omitted setting a custom page transition, but you can do it if you're using a custom page transition in your app.

Btw if you want to simplify that code, I guess you can just use `this.navCtrl.navigateBack("/home");` directly since the `NavController` in Ionic 5 uses Angular's router behind the scenes (as can be seen **[here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/f94e618a7b307b143eb39c061dc9e6b80e11f862/angular/src/providers/nav-controller.ts#L194)**).